# Formula in Excel to get back as a result the sum (of the selected cells of a certain column) in a dynamic table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, countif

I am trying to get back as a result the sum (the sum of the cells of a certain column) in a dynamic table. To give some context, I want a formula that automatically sums the values of a whole column, on a dynamic table with specific conditions:

In short, a formula that gives me the sum of the values of the column J, after I apply filters to the columns E, H, L, M and R!

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you try `SUBTOTAL` yet? Or maybe `SUMIFS` if by "filter" you mean "condition"?

Comment: AGGREGATE would be another option.